# Htaccess Rewrite Rule for with /admin/ for many rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect my website in following.

> 1. /admin/        ==>  /home.php
> 2. /admin/Log-In  ==>  /login.php
> 3. /admin/Log-Out ==>  /logout.php

All files are in root itself. There is no folder like "admin"

my rule is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/   /home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/Log-Out   /logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/Log-In   /login.php [NC,L]
```

But whenever I try to access `/admin/Log-In` its having redirect loop error, seem the server is accessing /home.php instead of `/login.php`

Can anyone help me to have the correct `htaccess` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$   /home.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/Log-Out   /logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/Log-In   /login.php [NC,L]
```

Because without $ (for end) it means "that begins with"... and therefore the next two are never called